# how to upgrade magento 2.1.0 to 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Install `Magento 2.1.0` in local server and need to upgrade `2.1.5`

If anyone knows, please help me How to run one command by one?

Comment: Easy Steps may be https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 7):

You can use following steps with composer update:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the Magento 2 version by using composer. Go to the root directory of Magento 2 via SSH and run the following commands

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update

composer update

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

If composer and Web Wizard all failed you have the third way:

1. Download the latest [Magento archive](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).
2. Unzip it into your root magento folder.
3. Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` ( if you are in production mode).

It helped me on a few occasions.

Take from [here](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-upgrade-service).